# C++ getting floats from line

Tags: c++

I'm creating OBJ file loader.

Here is a part of my .obj file:

```
v  0.012  0.032  0.023
v  0.232  0.0323  1.013
v  0.0123  1.031  0.2310
```

What is the best way to get those 3 different floats from one line?

I'm using std::ifstream.

I'm looking for a function like a Float.parseFloat from Java.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate components by spaces, now you have an array of strings. Cast float value to each string. Place new float values into strings using format identifiers (`%f`) and check if string made from the float value is equal to the original corresponding string. 
(e.g. (string)0.012 == @"0.012" but (string)0 != @"v")

---

*(I'm assuming 'v' casted to float returns 0, it may return unicode values I suppose but in any event it won't return 'v' because that's not a valid float. So this will still work)*

---

*Seperate the original file by `\n` to get the lines, once you have the line you want seperate its' components by   spaces